# Querying IMF API with imfr - error no result/does not accept filter

Tags: r, api, httr, economics

I am currently trying to download a particular series from the Direction Of Trade Statistics at the IMF for a calculation of trade volumes between countries. There is a r-package [`imfr`](https://github.com/cran/imfr) that does a fantastic job at doing this. However, when going for a particular set, I run into problems.

This code, works just fine and gets me the full data-series I am interested in for the fiven countries:

```
library(imfr)

# get the list of imf datasets 
imf_ids()

# I am interested in direction of trade "DOT", so check the list of codes that are in the datastructure
imf_codelist(database_id = "DOT")

# I want the export and import data between countries FOB so "TXG_FOB_USD" and "TMG_FOB_USD"
imf_codes("CL_INDICATOR_DOT")

# works nicely for exports:
data_list_exports <- imf_data(database_id = "DOT", indicator = c("TXG_FOB_USD"), 
                      country = c("US","JP","KR"), 
                      start = "1995",
                      return_raw = TRUE, 
                      freq = "A")

# however the same code does not work for imports
data_list_imports <- imf_data(database_id = "DOT", indicator = c("TMG_FOB_USD"), 
                                                  country = c("US","JP","KR"), 
                                                  start = "1995",
                                                  return_raw = TRUE, 
                                                  freq = "A")
```

This will return an empty series and I did not understand why. So I thought, maybe the US is not in the dataset (although unlikely)

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite) 
# look at the API endpoint, that provides us with the data structure behind a dataset
result <- httr::GET("http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/DataStructure/DTO") %>% httr::content(as = "parsed") 

structure_url <- "http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/DataStructure/DOT"

raw_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(structure_url )
test <- raw_data$Structure$CodeLists
```

However, the result indicates that indeed the US is in the data. So what if I just don´t specify a country? The result finally does download the data, but only the 60 first countries because of rate limits. When doing the same with an httr::GET I directly hit the rate limit and get an error back.

```
data_list_imports <- imf_data(database_id = "DOT", indicator = c("TMG_FOB_USD"), 
                                                  start = "1995",
                                                  return_raw = TRUE, 
                                                  freq = "A")
```

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong? I am really at a loss and just hope it is a typo somewhere...

Thanks and all the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of answers the question:

cjyetman over at github gave me the following hint:

> You can use the print_url = TRUE argument to see the actual API call.
>
> With...
>
> ```
> imf_data(database_id = "DOT", indicator = c("TMG_FOB_USD"), 
>          country = c("US","JP","KR"), 
>          start = "1995",
>          return_raw = TRUE, 
>          freq = "A", 
>          print_url = TRUE)
> ```
>
> you get...
> http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/CompactData/DOT/.US+JP+KR.TMG_FOB_USD?startPeriod=1995&endPeriod=2021
>
> which does not return any data.
>
> But if you add "AU" as a country to that list, you do get data with...
> http://dataservices.imf.org/REST/SDMX_JSON.svc/CompactData/DOT/.AU+US+JP+KR.TMG_FOB_USD?startPeriod=1995&endPeriod=2021
>
> So I guess either there is something wrong currently with their API,
> or they actually do not have data for specifically that indicator for
> those countries with that frequency, etc.

This does work indeed and makes apparent that either there is truly "missing data" in the API, or I am simply looking for data, where there is none. Since the original quest was to look at trade volumes, I have since found out, that the import value is usually used, with the [CIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incoterms#Cost,_Insurance_and_Freight) value and not [FOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOB_(shipping)).
Hence the correct indicator for the API call would have been the following:

```
library(imfr)
data_list_imports <- imf_data(database_id = "DOT", indicator = c("TMG_CIF_USD"), 
                                                  country = c("US","JP","KR"), 
                                                  start = "1995",
                                                  return_raw = TRUE, 
                                                  freq = "A")
```